# Catch a dynamic variable by using POST

Tags: php

I write two file `main.php` and `download.php`.

**main.php**

```
echo"<form action='download.php' method='post'>"
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    echo"<input type='submit' name='$i'>";
}
```

In `download.php`, I want to know which name's button is pressed? (from 1 to 10 to download the file), so that I can use it in download.php to download file.

I have tried to use $_POST["$i"] but failed.

What if the $i is a random filename?

Thx!

complete code

main.php:http://codepad.org/4zXPhqFy

Comment: I've done an update in my answer, it's easier and better, please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access `$_POST` via `$key => $value` in a loop.  Exclude other values you know the names of (if you have others).

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  // Look for form keys not among other known ones
  if (!in_array($key, array('other','known','input','names')) {
    echo "You clicked $key";
  }
}
```

Or, use `ctype_digit()` on the post key to determine if it is numeric, excluding any other string keys you may have in there.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  if (ctype_digit($key)) {
    echo "You clicked $key";
    // Access it via $_POST[$key]
  }
}
```

Note that unless you are using HTML5, `name` attributes must begin with a letter, not a number.  If you are using HTML5, anything but an empty string is allowable in the `name`.

Comment: But I want to use $_POST[the button has pressed] after, what should I do?

Comment: If the $i is filename, is there a way?

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Using my second example above, it will return the numeric key in $_POST via `$_POST[$key]`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should to start the submit's names with letters, not digits. And if you want buttons from 1 to 10 your `$i`must start with 1, not 0.

Try do to this:

**main.php**

```
echo '<form action="download.php" method="post">';

for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
    echo '<input type="submit" name="button[' . $i . ']" value="Send" />';
}
```

echo ''

**download.php**

```
if( isset($_POST['button']) )
{
    $button = key($_POST['button']);

    echo 'Button ' . $button . ' was clicked';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution

build the buttons

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  echo '<input type="submit" name="button[' .  chr($i+64) . ']"/>';
}
```

I did the chr so that you can see it can be any text

Find out which was pressed

```
echo 'button ' . key($_POST['button']) . ' was pressed';
```

The advantage of this way, is you do not need a loop to find out the button that was pressed